# Changing domain of already installed fullscreen PWA

Tags: progressive-web-apps

I have a PWA running in production installed on many of my users devices on `https://domain1.com` and I want to move it to `https://domain2.com`.

I did a redirect on `domain1.com` however on onAndroid installed PWA app, instead of staying full screen, the app suddenly shows a browser-bar at top, as if it's in-app browser treating the new url as external to the app.

Is it possible to make this change without telling them to all uninstall and reinstall? Maybe modifying the manifest? I looked into `start_url` but I'm not sure it works.

Comment: Did you find a solution?

Comment: @nxoo the only way I found was to uninstall and then re-install